# Database cannot be opened because it is version 869. this server supports version 852 and earlier

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

So I am facing an error while attaching my SQL database .mdf file to my SQL server 2019. SQL server showing me the error like below:

> Database cannot be opened because it is version 869. this server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported..

I am using SQL server latest version with express edition. and note here database came from another PC but I'm using the latest version then why this is happening to me. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: [Because you are actually connecting to a SQL Server 2016 instance, while attempting to restore a database created by SQL Server 2017](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html). Double check what instance you're connecting to; your machine may have more than one version installed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so you want to say that I need to uninstall the SQL server 2019 version and then need to install the 2017 version right???

Comment: No, I don't. I mean that you've either not installed SQL Server 2019 to begin with, or you're not connecting to it (for example, you need to connect to `localhost` instead of `localhost\sqlexpress`, or vice versa). There is no need to install SQL Server 2017 if you can (or have) installed SQL Server 2019; SQL Server is backwards compatible (but not forwards).

Comment: @JeroenMostert okay, I am trying and then I will update here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Maybe solution for your problem:

These setting made it working for me and I had same error as you.

Choose ./SQLEXPRESS option instead of (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB and it should get it working.

[image: This will connect your app with database file so you can query your database]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1- Uninstall SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB

2- Delete remaining folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\

3- Install SQL Server Express 2019 LocalDB :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

4- Run

SqlLocalDB create MSSQLLocalDB

sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB

[LocalDb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6qy0.jpg)

**SQL Server Express LocalDB 2019 is now install in Visual Studio 2022.
You can download the preview version of Visual Studio 2022 from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/**